# Fast, portable conversion of 24 bit ints to float without losing a bit

Tags: floating-point, tensorflow

When generating random uniform floats in `[0, 1)`, TensorFlow currently uses [bit twiddling](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ed6f783690a35e54441881930d4291894bc03285/tensorflow/core/lib/random/random_distributions.h#L402) to convert 23 bit integers to floats in `[1, 2)`, then subtracts one:

```
// Helper function to convert an 32-bit integer to a float between [0..1).
PHILOX_DEVICE_INLINE float Uint32ToFloat(uint32 x) {
  // IEEE754 floats are formatted as follows (MSB first):
  //    sign(1) exponent(8) mantissa(23)
  // Conceptually construct the following:
  //    sign == 0
  //    exponent == 127  -- an excess 127 representation of a zero exponent
  //    mantissa == 23 random bits
  const uint32 man = x & 0x7fffffu;  // 23 bit mantissa
  const uint32 exp = static_cast<uint32>(127);
  const uint32 val = (exp << 23) | man;

  // Assumes that endian-ness is same for float and uint32.
  float result;
  memcpy(&result, &val, sizeof(val));
  return result - 1.0f;
}
```

This irritates me, since subtracting one means we only get 23 bits of precision, rather than the 24 bits available.  Unfortunately, the naive algorithm is about 9% slower on CPUs (it's the same speed on GPU):

```
// Helper function to convert an 32-bit integer to a float between [0..1).
PHILOX_DEVICE_INLINE float Uint32ToFloat(uint32 x) {
  return 0x1p-32f * static_cast<float>(x);
}
```

I also tried explicitly truncating to 24 bits in case it would teach the compiler that rounding mode flags didn't matter; this didn't solve the problem:

```
PHILOX_DEVICE_INLINE float Uint32ToFloat(uint32 x) {
  return 0x1p-24f * static_cast<float>(x & ((1 << 24) - 1));
}
```

Is there a way to get the full 24 bits of available precision without sacrificing performance?  I'm pretty sure I could do it in assembly, but portability is required.

Note that the remaining 8 bits of precision that one can get *sometimes* for small floats are not interesting: I only care about the one missing bit.

Answer (score 3):

You can try not doing the subtraction when the 24th bit is set:

```
  …
  const uint32 exp = static_cast<uint32>(126); // 0.5
  …
  if ((x & 0x800000) == 0) result -= 0.5f;
  return result;
}
```

However, just 9% penalty for the 24th bit is already pretty good, and this will not necessarily be faster. (Here you are sometimes avoiding the price of a subtraction, but always paying the price of a test and conditional branch. I will let you do the timings: the 0x800000 mask can be done in parallel with the rest but the cost of the conditional branch  entirely depends on the distribution of the values in practice.)

This can easily be made branchless for GPUs by always doing the subtraction followed by a conditional move, but the compiler should do this automatically.

Comment: That's very clever!  I will give it a try soon and report back.  Conveniently, this produces bitwise identical results my third block of code above (the 24 bit version), so I could optionally #ifdef it to use the simple version on GPUs.

Comment: Ah, I suddenly notice that you state the distribution in the question: “When generating random uniform floats in [0, 1)”… that's not going to be a best case for branch prediction :( It may be advantageous to make it branchless by computing `0.5f `or `0.0f` from `x & 0x800000` in the cheapest possible way and always subtracting it.

Comment: Yes, this will only be fast if it's branch free, but that seems entirely practical.

Comment: Hmm: 0.5f's binary form is 0x3f000000, so one option would be to pick a rescale such that 0.5 is a single bit, construct the scaled version of 0.5 from some chosen bit of x, then add a bit to the exponent.  Would need to benchmark to see if that's reasonable, though.

Comment: On x86, just doing a multiply of 0x3f00... * ((x & 0x80000) >> 19)
might just be fast enough - integer mul is shockingly fast.  On GPU, you could instead use 0x3f00000 & ((x & 0x80000) == 0x80000));  nvidia sets the result of true equality comparison to all-1s.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `__builtin_clz` to directly adjust the exponent and map the remainder of the number as the mantissa, avoiding the floating point subtraction and the loss of precision:

```
float Uint32ToFloat(uint32_t x) {
  // IEEE754 floats are formatted as follows (MSB first):
  //    sign(1) exponent(8) mantissa(23)
  // Conceptually construct the following:
  //    sign == 0
  //    exponent == 126  -- an excess 127 representation of a -1 exponent
  //    mantissa == 23 random bits
  uint32_t exp = static_cast<uint32_t>(126);

  auto lz = __builtin_clz(x);
  exp -= lz;
  x <<= (lz+1);  // +1 to chop off implicit 1 in FP representation.
  const uint32_t man = x >> 9;  // 23 bit mantissa.
  const uint32_t val = (exp << 23) | man;

  // Assumes that endian-ness is same for float and uint32.
  float result;
  memcpy(&result, &val, sizeof(val));
  return result;
}
```

Note that the CUDA equivalent of gcc's `__builtin_clz` is `__clz()`.

Advantages:  Preserves as much precision as possible from the original random number.

Drawback:  I think the original version vectorizes better and has a bit less instruction latency.

A third alternative is to directly adjust the exponent after letting the FP hardware do the conversion from the integer:

```
inline float Uint32ToFloat_bit(uint32_t x) {
  float f(x);
  uint32_t f_as_int;
  memcpy(&f_as_int, &f, sizeof(f_as_int));
  f_as_int -= (32 << 23);  // Subtract 32 from the exponent.
  float result;
  memcpy(&result, &f_as_int, sizeof(f_as_int));
  return result;
}
```

This was faster than the builtin_clz version for me, but slower than your basic one, but I again suspect it's very context-dependent.  This one might vectorize quite well - but so does your very basic one, since it's just a `vmulss`.

After having gone through all of this, I think that the best step would be a timing harness that produces a batch of 8 random numbers and then bulk converts them, to let the compiler vectorize the conversions, and then see which is best.

Comment: Benchmarked them on avx2 within tensorflow - the conditional subtract and the clz versions seem pretty similar.  The direct exponent manipulation is slower.  The `0x1p-32f * static_cast<float>(x)` version is also slower.